# For what $C^*$ algebras $A$ do different types of projection equivalence agree?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, at.algebraic-topology, oa.operator-algebras

For example,

- For what $C^*$ algebras $A$ is unitary equivalence the same as mvn equivalence for projections.
- For what $C^*$ algebras $A$ is unitary equivalence the same as homotopy equivalence for projections.
- For what $C^*$ algebras $A$ is unitary equivalence the same as approximate unitary equivalence

Of course it's already known that $p \sim_h q \implies p \sim_u q \implies p \sim_{mvn} q$, so I suppose my question is when do we have implications in the other direction. One thing I've already noticed is that for (some nontrivial) classes of $C^*$ algebras there are so few projections that this line of questioning is meaningless.

So far I've seen remarkably few results contrasting the different types of projections, and the only well-known result I've seen is that if $A$ is unital then $p \sim_u q \iff p \sim_{mvn} q $ and $ 1-p \sim_{mvn} 1-q$.

I'm aware this might be a bit of a weird/unnatural question to ask. It's definitely quite "operator first", which is probably a feature of someone that's been reading a lot of Davidson's book recently! This is just because I'm still at the stage of my Ph.D. of asking questions that aren't necessarily interesting. I would equally be interested in hearing about why or why not there is not so much interest in these types of questions.

I feel thinking about these questions might help deepen my understanding/appreciation of the construction of $K_0$... I suppose it's true that if we had mvn equivalence in some $M_n(A)$, we can blow it up to a larger matrix (would it be respectively $M_{2n}, M_{4n}$?) such that we have unitary/homotopy equivalence. Is this why people don't generally look at what distinguishes these equivalence at the level of $A$?

Comment: For the third question: approximate unitary equivalence of projections is the same unitary equivalence, since close projections are unitarily equivalent.

Comment: Aha, that was a silly mistake. Hope you are well Jamie.

Comment: I wanted to comment that upon some further searching, there is some movement in some areas back in the 90s. 

[This paper by Sang Og Kim](https://www.koreascience.or.kr/article/JAKO199711919488693.pdf) is relevant to the second question.

Comment: The questions feel too general to have a better answer than the description you've given(maybe restricting to classifiable C*-algebras it may be known?). On the other hand, for a large and interesting class of C*-algebras Rieffel has settled the first question. He showed (Corollary 7.8 in Projective Modules over higher dimensional non-commutative tori) that in a (irrational) non commutative torus $A$ if two projections $p,q\in M_n(A)$ have the same $K_0$ class then they are actually unitarily equivalent.  So Rieffel's paper may be a fun/good place to start investigating the first question

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot for the recommendation! Will check it out Caleb.

Comment: Moreover, homotopy, unitary, and Murray-von Neumann equivalence agree for projections in a stable C*-algebra, i.e.~a C*-algebra $A$ such that $A \cong A \otimes \mathcal K(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$. Here the unitaries can be taken in the minimal unitisation or in the multiplier algebra $M(A)$. This follows since if $p,q\in Proj(A)$ then $1-p, 1-q \in M(A)$ are equivalent (easy exercise using stability), and since the unitary group of $M(A)$ is path-connected by a theorem of Cuntz and Higson (although you can prove homotopy equivalence from unitary equiv. bare hands).